# looping through firebase data

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Hi I am trying to access nested data in firebase real time database with a cloud functions, my data looks like:

```js
{
  "RANGE1": {
    "left": 2,
    "overlayImage": "",
    "right": 1,
    "submittedInfo": {
      "left_1": {
        "TimeStamp": "2020-02-16 19:05:35",
        "horozontalAccuracy": 10,
        "latitude": 0000,
        "longitude": 0000
      },
      "left_2": {
        "TimeStamp": "2020-02-16 19:23:59",
        "horozontalAccuracy": 10,
        "latitude": 0000,
        "longitude": 0000
      },
      "left_3": {
        "TimeStamp": "2020-02-20 19:35:28",
        "horozontalAccuracy": 10,
        "latitude": 0000,
        "longitude": 0000
      },
      "right_1": {
        "TimeStamp": "2020-02-16 19:08:30",
        "horozontalAccuracy": 10,
        "latitude": 0000,
        "longitude": 0000
      }
    }
  },
  "RANGE2": {
    "left": 1,
    "overlayImage": "",
    "right": 1,
    "submittedInfo": {
      "left_1": {
        "TimeStamp": "2020-02-12 22:07:11",
        "horozontalAccuracy": 5,
        "latitude": 0000,
        "longitude": 0000
      },

      "right_1": {
        "TimeStamp": "2020-02-12 22:36:36",
        "horozontalAccuracy": 11.721012922544011,
        "latitude": 0000,
        "longitude": 0000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I have a function that is supposed to filter and flatten this data. But I can't seem to figure out how to get deep in to the nodes. everything I try I seem to get stuck in accessing [object Object] or the typeof() returns a string when it should be a JSON object still

```js
 admin.database().ref(".../range").once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    var flagInfo = [];
    snapshot.forEach((range) => {
        console.log("range is : " + range) // [object Object]
        console.log("range[submitted] " + range['submittedInfo']) // undefined???
        // what I need to do is something like: 
        range["submittedInfo"].forEach((flagData) => { 
            console.log(flagData.key)
            console.log(flagData["latitude"]) // and so on for the rest of the keys
        }) // end 
})
```

Comment: can you add accepted output

Comment: Type error, "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined". The error happens at the range["submittedInfo"].foreach((flagData) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look on [this reference.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#foreach) There is quite good example in forEach part.

You should use methods `child()` and `val()`. I do not have testing playground at hand at the moment, but it should be something like `range.val()` to get range and `range.child('submittedInfo').val()` to get 'submittedInfo' data, but you have to figure it out how to do it exactly. If you will not manage let me know, I will try to implement it on my side.

I hope it will help!